# How to get the test name from a TestCleanup method?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I notice that a `[TestCleanup]` method cannot take a `TestContext` parameter. How then I am supposed to know which test is being cleanup up?

Comment: Do you need to know about the test being cleaned up for any specific reason?

Answer (score 6):

You can have a public property named `TestContext` on your class and that will be set by MSTest, for example :

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var x = 2;
        var y = 1 + 1;
        Assert.AreEqual(x, y);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(true, true);
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(TestContext.TestName);
    }
}
```